# Solution for this first order non linear DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$$
\frac{dS}{dt} = q - YX\mu \frac{S}{S + K}
$$

where q is constant in t, Y is a constant, X can be considered constant as dt is very small, K is a constant, S(0)=0.

I'm struggling with the separation of the variables to write the expression for S(t). I'm aware that working with t(S) instead yields an expression:
$$
S(t)-\alpha^{-1}\ln(1+\alpha S(t))=t
$$
Where: 
$$ \alpha=\frac{q-\mu XY}{\mu XYK} $$

But I do not know how this was derived. If someone could help me out through the rationale behind solving it this way or solving this for an explicit expression for S(t), it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered a Laplace Transform approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation is separable. Namely, we can write $$\frac{S'(t)}{q-\mu XY\frac{S(t)}{S(t)+K}} = \frac{(K+S(t))S'(t)}{qK+(q-\mu XY)S(t)} = 1$$ which implies $$\int \frac{(K+S(t))S'(t)}{qK+(q-\mu XY)S(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t = \int 1\,\mathrm{d}t$$ Applying partial fractions and integrating gives us $$\frac{S(t)}{q-\mu XY}-\frac{\mu KXY}{(q-\mu XY)^2}\log(qK+(q-\mu XY)S(t)) = t+C$$ Plugging in $t = 0$ gives us $$C = -\frac{\mu KXY\log(qK)}{(q-\mu XY)^2}$$ so we can move this to the left-hand side of the equation to get $$\frac{S(t)}{q-\mu XY}-\frac{\mu KXY}{(q-\mu XY)^2}\log\left(1+\frac{q-\mu XY}{qK}S(t)\right) = t$$